# Read bits from double in HLSL

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, hlsl

I am trying to convert a bits library of mine from C# to HLSL, but I am unable to convert 2 functions that use bitwise operators on doubles

```cs
    static public int getBits(int start, int end, long value)
    {
        long mask = ((1L << (end - start + 1)) - 1) << start;
        int result = (int)((value & mask) >> start);

        return result;
    }

    static public int getBits(int start, int end, long value)
    {
        long mask = ((1L << (end - start + 1)) - 1) << start;
        int result = (int)((value & mask) >> start);

        return result;
    }
```

I have tried

```c
int getBits(int start, int end, double value)
{
    uint mask = ((1 << (end - start + 1)) - 1) << start;
    uint valueAsUintLow, valueAsUintHigh;
    asuint(value, valueAsUintLow, valueAsUintHigh); // Extract the low and high 32 bits of value

    uint maskedValueLow = valueAsUintLow & mask; // Get the masked bits from the low bits
    uint maskedValueHigh = valueAsUintHigh & (mask >> 32); // Get the masked bits from the high bits

    int result = (int)(maskedValueLow | (maskedValueHigh << start)); // Combine the low and high bits

    return result;
}
```

But it always returns a wrong int

I want it to return the same thing that the C# script returns

Comment: Bump, why does no one reply to this

Answer (score 0):

In your C# code you're doing bitwise operations on a Long which is an integer stored as based 2.  In your HSLS code your doing bitwise operations on a double which is stored using floating point notation.  You're trying to manipulate the underlying bits, but those underlying bits are not the same which is why you are getting different results.

At a minimum they both need to be integers, but to get consistent results you probably need to make the C# value an Int32 and the HSLS value an int.